# Laravel querybuilder returns PHP warning explode

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I have a raw query that I want to convert into querybuilder since I need to modify it. Here is the old query

```
SELECT
    mws_name,
    MAX(created_at) as created_at,
    updated_at,
    SUM(pending) as pending,
    SUM(approved) as approved,
    SUM(rejected) as rejected
FROM (
    SELECT 
        um.mws_name,
        ac.users_mws_id,
        ac.case_type,
        ac.created_at,
        ac.pending,
        ac.approved,
        ac.rejected,
        ac.updated_at
    FROM admin_case_info ac
    JOIN users_mws um ON ac.users_mws_id = um.id
) AS acum
GROUP BY acum.users_mws_id 
ORDER BY MAX(acum.created_at) asc
LIMIT 10
```

What I tried is

```
DB::select([
    'mws_name',
    DB::raw('MAX(created_at) as created_at'),
    'updated_at',
    DB::raw('SUM(pending) as pending'),
    DB::raw('SUM(approved) as approved'),
    DB::raw('SUM(rejected) as rejected'),
])
    ->fromSub(function ($query) {
        $query->select([
            'um.mws_name',
            'ac.users_mws_id',
            'ac.case_type',
            'ac.created_at',
            'ac.pending',
            'ac.approved',
            'ac.rejected',
            'ac.updated_at',
        ])->from('admin_case_info as ac')
        ->join('users_mws as um', 'ac.users_mws_id', '=', 'um.id');
    }, 'acum')
    ->groupBy('acum.users_mws_id')
    ->orderByRaw('MAX(acum.created_at) asc')
    ->limit(10)
    ->get();
```

When I tried to call it in tinker it returns
`PHP Warning:  explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in D:/Projects/recon-admin/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Str.php on line 414`

Does anyone know what I did wrong? Thanks

Comment: DB::select() is different from Model::select(), you can pass the whole SQL statement to DB::select, but you only pass the select section to Model::select()

Comment: what do you mean sir? I did not use model for my query

Comment: you should write the whole query e.g. DB::select("SELECT * FROM users_ms")

Comment: So it is impossible to write it in a querybuilder manner? @AnuratChapanond

Comment: usually it looks like DB::table('admin_case_info')->...

Comment: can you write the query for me sir? @AnuratChapanond